# howto create multiple records in a single form with same values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am looking for a clean solution to create multiple database records from a single form, that  all have the same values specified in the form. Only the ID should obviously be different.

I need this function to let the user create 100+ records at once as a kind of templating.

So ideally in the form the user can type a number for the count of records she/he would like to create with the filled in values.

Comment: Is your DB is MySQL or SQL DB or Oracle?

Comment: a "little" late, sorry. It's postgresql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an iterator. Example:

```
def create_many
  count = params[:count].to_i
  # count within reasonable limits, check if object will validate
  if (1..100) === count && Object.new(params[:object]).valid?
    count.times { Object.create(params[:object]) }   # <= the iterator
    redirect_to my_custom_view   # <= custom 'show' view
  else
    render :text => "Couldn't do it."   # <= failure message
  end
end
```

This example expects two parameters, `:object` which contains resource attributes, and `:count` which specifies how many records to create.

You need a custom `show` view to handle getting and displaying all of the newly created records.